# Is there any fulfillment timeout in WP8 in-app purchasing?

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

If user of my App buys consumable product, how much time do I have to send fulfilling of this product? May I do it in, for example, 2 weeks?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advce?

Comment: May be... Where should I ask this question in such case?

Comment: You'd contact your attorney. Given laws vary from country to country, there isn't a good place to ask legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

According In-app purchase article in MSDN -

*Fulfillment is the process of making sure that your customers get the goods they purchased in a timely manner. For an app, this typically means as soon as the purchase has been verified.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206949(v=vs.105).aspx

see section Fulfilling purchases

Comment: And what if I've verified the purchase and haven't sent fulfillment by some reasons (for ex. lost of internet connection)? What happens then? When the user money back?